# AWS User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, auth0, serverless

I am deploying a serverless app on AWS and have some issues while trying to access my serverless application from the frontend.  I have an impression that the issue is with the backend and more specifically with the serverless.yml  configuration file (See first lines of codes below) or rather with my auth0Authorizer.ts file (see second lines of codes below). When I log into my frontend app, I receive a 403 error message that says `User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny`. I really doubt if this related any on configuration on AWS.

```
    org: name
app: serverless-todo-app-app
service:
  name: serverless-todo-app
package:
  individually: true

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
  - serverless-aws-documentation

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-west-1'}

  tracing: true

  environment:
    TODOS_TABLE: Todos-v4-${self:provider.stage}
    USER_ID_INDEX: UserIdIndex
    SIGNED_URL_EXPIRATION: 300 
    IMAGES_S3_BUCKET: 'severless-todo-app-bucket-v1-${self:provider.stage}'
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: TableName 
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}
    AUTH_0_SECRET: ***********************************
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - codedeploy:*
        - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
        - xray:PutTraceSegments
      Resource:
        - '*'
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:GetObject
        - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
        - xray:PutTraceSegments     
      Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}/*

custom:
  documentation:
    api:
      info:
        version: v1.0.0
        title: Udagram API
        description: Serverless application
    models:
      - name: TodoRequest
        contentType: application/json
        schema: ${file(models/create-todo-request.json)}


functions:

  Auth:
    handler: src/lambda/auth/auth0Authorizer.handler

  # TODO: Configure this function
  GetTodos:
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:Query
          - dynamodb:GetItem
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

    handler: src/lambda/http/getTodos.handler
    events:
      - http:
          authorizer: Auth
          method: get
          path: todos
          cors: true


  # TODO: Configure this function
  CreateTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/createTodo.handler
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
          - xray:PutTraceSegments
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}
    events:
      - http:
          authorizer: Auth
          method: post
          path: todos
          cors: true
          reqValidatorName: RequestBodyValidator
          documentation:
            summary: Create a new todo
            description: Create a new todo
            requestModels:
              'application/json': TodoRequest
  # TODO: Configure this function
  UpdateTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/updateTodo.handler
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
          - xray:PutTraceSegments
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

    events:
      - http:
          authorizer: Auth
          method: patch
          path: todos/{todoId}
          cors: true
  # TODO: Configure this function
  DeleteTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/deleteTodo.handler
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

    events:
      - http:
          authorizer: Auth
          method: delete
          path: todos/{todoId}
          cors: true

  # TODO: Configure this function
  GenerateUploadUrl:
    handler: src/lambda/http/generateUploadUrl.handler
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:PutObject
          - s3:GetObject
          - xray:PutTelemetryRecords
          - xray:PutTraceSegments
        Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}/*
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}

    events:
      - http:
          authorizer: Auth
          method: post
          path: todos/{todoId}/attachment
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    # TODO: Add any necessary AWS resources
    AttachmentsBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            -
              AllowedOrigins:
                - '*'
              AllowedHeaders:
                - '*'
              AllowedMethods:
                - GET
                - PUT
                - POST
                - DELETE
                - HEAD
              MaxAge: 0

    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: MyPolicy
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Action: 's3:GetObject'
              Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.IMAGES_S3_BUCKET}/*'
        Bucket: !Ref AttachmentsBucket


    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS,POST'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi

    RequestBodyValidator:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
      Properties:
        Name: 'request-body-validator'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
        ValidateRequestParameters: false

    TodosDynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: todoId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: todoId
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.USER_ID_INDEX}
            KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: userId
              KeyType: HASH

            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
```

```
import { CustomAuthorizerEvent, CustomAuthorizerResult, CustomAuthorizerHandler } from 'aws-lambda'
import 'source-map-support/register'
import { verify } from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { JwtToken } from '../../auth/JwtToken'

const auth0Secret = process.env.AUTH_0_SECRET
export const handler: CustomAuthorizerHandler = async (event: CustomAuthorizerEvent): Promise<CustomAuthorizerResult> => {
  try {
    const decodedToken = verifyToken(event.authorizationToken)
    console.log('User was authorized')

    return {
      principalId: decodedToken.sub,
      policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Resource: '*'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('User was not authorized', e.message)

    return {
      principalId: 'user',
      policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: 'Deny',
            Resource: '*'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

function verifyToken(authHeader: string): JwtToken {
  if (!authHeader)
    throw new Error('No authentication header')

  if (!authHeader.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer '))
    throw new Error('Invalid authentication header')

  const split = authHeader.split(' ')
  const token = split[1]

  return verify(token, auth0Secret) as JwtToken
}
```

Comment: You're passing a session policy in the error block of your code. If your code produces an error, your session policy with the `Deny` on the `execute-api:Invoke` will be applied. Check the logs of the error that's being thrown.

Answer (score 5):

When AWS says explicit Deny that means somewhere in the chain of IAM policies, there was a Deny for that action. In this case the only policy is the session policy that your authorizer Lambda provides. As @hephalump mentioned in the comments and according to your code it happens when there was an error, so check the logs to see what needs to be done.